# How to sprint and stop on button clicked?

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I just need my character to sprint when I press the 'r' button and again stop running when I press the 'r' button again. By default, I have to hold the w key to run, but is there a way to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to achieve both of those things. Just set a variable called 'isRunning' or 'isPrinting' to true, and if you've watched some tutorials, you'll see the Axis Value from Axis Mappings being used for some things. Give it a value of either 1, 0, or -1.

To make your character run without pressing on the key, instead of linking it to the Input Event, just do that on your Tick Event and set the value to either 1, -1 or 0 depending on the boolean.